# How to add CSS class in PHP if/else statement?

Tags: php, css, class, if-statement

I wrote this code to  add css class to a post title. it works in wordpress. I think it is correct code but not working

```
<h2><a  <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hot',true) == 'on') { ?>class="hottitle" <?php } ?> title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

but it dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this using ternary operator.

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hot',true);
// Check if the custom field has a value.
<h2><a  <?php echo (! empty( $key_1_value )) ? 'class="hottitle"' : '';  ?> title="<?php echo get_the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Refer this link for more information https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: not working.  look at this please:  <h1 <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hot',true) == 'on') { ?> class="hottitle" <?php } ?> > <a    title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

Comment: @kowsaralipour Please try this 

 <h1 <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hot',true) == 'on') { ?> class="hottitle" <?php } ?> > <a title="<?php echo get_the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php echo  get_the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h1>

Comment: @kowsaralipour also i have updated my ans please check.

Comment: thanks.  but  i think this part : " 'on') ? 'class"  isn't correct

Comment: @kowsaralipour please try only using this if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hot',true)). also updated in ans.

Comment: its returne correct ans with or whitout that.  but dont change style. might you think this can related to css problem?    h1.hottitle {
    color: #1aa51f !important
}

Comment: @kowsaralipour did you get class on h1/h2 tag ?

Comment: put this alone or with something?

Comment: @kowsaralipour just add one line and replace if condition.

Comment: @kowsaralipour if answer is usefull then please approve and upvott !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2><a <?php=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'hot',true)=='on'?'class="hottitle"':''?> title="<?php=the_title_attribute();?>" href="<?php=the_permalink()?>"><?php=the_title()?></a></h2>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `<?php=`

Comment: bro I'm using it every day, please check it

Comment: It's either `<?=` or `<?php` or (if for some reason you use short tags) `<?`.That's it.